# Exclude list entries with lambdas

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two lists of same type:

```
final List<MyType> myCurrentList = ... 
final List<MyType> listFromDatabase = ...
```

`MyType` looks like this:

```
class MyType {

   private DateTime startDate; 
   ...
}
```

Now I will get all `MyType` objects of `myCurrentList` where there is no entry of the same `startDate` in `listFromDatabase`.

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you face? Hint: start by transforming the second list to a Set<DateTime>. Then use a filter to filter the first list.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should collect all the `startTime`s from the database, preferably to a `Set` (since you only care about the dates being present there, not about multiple occurrences or their order):

```
Set<DateTime> datesFromDatabase =
    listFromDatabase.stream()
                    .map(MyTime::getStartTime)                        
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Then, you can stream the current list, and retain only the objects that don't have a date in the database:

```
List<MyType> filteredList = 
    myCurrentList.stream()
                 .filter(x -> !datesFromDatabase.contains(x.getStartTime())
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: FYI The current (likely every) impl of `toSet()` returns a `HashSet`, so the predicate will perform in O(1) time. Good answer.